# How do I store and retrieve an array of classes from the Windows Registry in .Net C#?

Tags: c#, .net, registry

Consider the following class and code snippet:

```
public class FooClass
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Description {get;set;}
   public int IntValue {get;Set;}
};

List<FooClass> myFooList = new List<FooClass>()
{
  new FooClass() { Name="Name1", Description="Desc1", IntValue=1},
  new FooClass() { Name="Name2", Description="Desc2", IntValue=2},
  new FooClass() { Name="Name2", Description="Desc2", IntValue=2},
};
```

The registry path is

```
HKLM:SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\MySoftwareName\MyEntries
```

I assume that each entry in the list would be a Key under MyEntries?
I know how to deal with simple key retrieval/updating.

How do I store this variable length list in the registry?
Should I stringify FooClass instances to JSON object?
Is there a well known pattern for doing this

Thanks, JohnB

Comment: Try to avoid using registry keys. You can save those objects in a JSON config file. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#bind-an-array

Comment: @LexLi - agreed, not a good design decision. Going with persisting to DB for to be able to add/remove. Thx